# Angularjs - individual directive width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

On my website I'm using this multiselect directive several places

http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main

For instance I'm using it in my navbar as a language selection dropdown. However I would like to specify the width of the language dropdown to less than standard. Other places I'm using the same directive and the auto width is fine. I can change the width of the language menu by changing min-width and max-width in the css file, but this will change the width of all my multiselects.

So basically, how can I change the css of just one particular instance of a directive?

[update]

The multiselect is added like this:

```
<div isteven-multi-select
         input-model="languages"
         output-model="outputlanguages"
         button-label="icon name"
         item-label="icon name maker"
         tick-property="ticked"
         selection-mode="single"
         helper-elements="filter"
         on-item-click="changeLanguage(data)"
            >
</div>
```

When the html is loaded the isteven-multi-select div will contain the following:

```
<span class="multiSelect inlineBlock">
     <button ...>
     </button>
     <div class="checkboxLayer"> //here is the dropmenu itself
     </div>
</span
```

So by editting .checkboxLayer in the css file I can adjust the width of the dropdown menu. But this is changed for all multiselect instances. It doesnt work if I add another class to the isteven-multi-select as this is the parent div.

Comment: can u add a fiddle ?

Comment: first add class to that select and than style it according your requirement..

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a css class to the div with the directive where you want the smaller dropdown:

```
<div isteven-multi-select
     input-model="languages"
     output-model="outputlanguages"
     button-label="icon name"
     item-label="icon name maker"
     tick-property="ticked"
     selection-mode="single"
     helper-elements="filter"
     on-item-click="changeLanguage(data)"

    <!-- Add this -->
     class="thinDropdown"   >
</div>
```

Then in your css, write this:

```
.thinDropdown .checkboxLayer {
    width: 200px;              /* Or whatever width you like */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for. Although it didnt work by specifying width, but setting min-width and max-width to 200 px did the trick.